# How to test unexpected return results in jUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing a test case for the Pacman game. One thing I am confused and not sure how to proceed.

I have a method `int move(int stpes);` It returns an `int` value and to indicates the Pacman movement steps.

For example, if `move(3)` returns 3, Pacman moved 3 steps.

If `move(3)` returns -1, that means Pacman died, eaten by ghost.

Now, the ghost movement was random, I have a different method handles this. So I my test case, I cannot control if the Pacman will die or not. So my test cases passes when ghost not eat Pacman. 
For instance, I use: `assertEquals(2, move(2));` to test Pacman moves 2 steps.But how do I write test when `-1` was returned?

UPDATE:

So here is what my `move()` method looks like, I have a ghost movement method `randomGhostMovement()` that gets called inside the `move()` method:

```
int move(int stpes){
    for(int i=0; i< steps; i++){
        randomGhostMovement();
        //rest of logic omitted.
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Looks like your problem is that you're hardcoding the random number generator that drives the game progress. To make you code testable you should allow injecting the random number generator from the outside so you can replace it with a "rigged" one that returns predictable "not-really-random" numbers for the tests.

Comment: @kryger That what I did. I have a method that randomly generating the ghost movement. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @kryger I updated my OP to show the `move()` method logic.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina updated my OP.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few different problems.

1. you have a method/class that does many different things. `move` takes x and returns x or -1. that's somehow complex and useless. how about having a class `GameState` with method `isPacmanDead`. in general: separate your game into many tiny steps and use logic-less layer to simply call them in a loop.
2. testing random numbers. refactor your code to be able to manually move ghosts and then create another logic-less layer that draws a random number and provide it to `moveGhost` method. then in your tests you can ignore the random layer and do fully deterministic tests. another useful technique is to use dependency injection to provide source-of-randomness and in tests mock it to it generates whatever values you wish

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java.util.Random, you can **provide a random seed**.

A random seed can be any `long` value.
Using the same random seed each time will guarantee the same random numbers are generated.

For example:

```
    long randomSeed = 1449443188342L;
    Random random = new Random(randomSeed);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("random number: " + random.nextInt(10));
    }
```

No matter how many times I run this code, I still get the same output:

```
random number: 3
random number: 2
random number: 7
random number: 8
random number: 0
```

If the random numbers generated each time are exactly the same, then the ghosts movement becomes predictable. You can set up a new game using a certain random seed, record what actions will cause Pacman to die, then write a test case which uses the exact same seed.